# How to get Vector in DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I get some Feature Vector using SparkML TF-IDF algorithm. Now I want to get the Vector in the column of "idfFeatures".

[image]

My code is:

```
val vectors = allDF.select("idfFeatures").map{
  case Row(vector: Vector) =>
    vector
}
vectors.foreach(println(_))
```

There is a bug in console:

```
Error:(38, 24) type Vector takes type parameters
  case Row(vector: Vector) =>
                   ^
```

If I change Vector to String, there is another bug:

```
scala.MatchError: [(262144,[622,4200,7303,8501......,2.1972245773362196,1.2809338454620642])] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)
at scala.TFIDFTest2$$anonfun$1.apply(TFIDFTest2.scala:37)
```

How can I get the Vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark 1.x:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
```

Spark 2.0:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
```

Example:

```
// https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#tf-idf

import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer}

val sentenceData = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
  (0, "I wish Java could use case classes"),
  (1, "Logistic regression models are neat")
)).toDF("label", "sentence")

val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("sentence").setOutputCol("words")
val wordsData = tokenizer.transform(sentenceData)
val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
  .setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("rawFeatures").setNumFeatures(20)
val featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)

val idf = new IDF().setInputCol("rawFeatures").setOutputCol("features")
val idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)

val idf = new IDF().setInputCol("rawFeatures").setOutputCol("features")
val idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)
val rescaledData = idfModel.transform(featurizedData)
```

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

rescaledData.select("features").rdd.map { case Row(v: Vector) => v}.first
```

Comment: I add it in Spark 2.0. but still print the bug. Can I divide the vector [A,[B],[C]] into 3 column (columnA,columnB,columnC)?

Comment: Very useful! Why can't import Vector at top?

Comment: You can. But the top part is just a copied example from the docs.

Comment: dont know if that helps, but I had the same problem and couldnt retrieve the vector from a spark sql DataFrame. What worked for me in the end was using `getAs` like this:\\  `row.getAs[Vector[Double]](0)` where 0 is the column index and Double the type of elements in my Vector

Comment: (if the DataFrame came from ML e.g. the result of transfrom, and I wanted to retrieve the probabilities then it worked like that:   `r.getAs[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector](1)`